# Which country is the best to incorporate business for a freelance developer?

Tags: taxes, business-plan

Most of my clients located in USA, however I have ability to open business in Europe, Asia or USA. Which country is the best in terms of taxation?

Thanks,

Comment: Best how? Low taxes? Ease of registering the company? Law? Requirements? It's too broad right now

Comment: Low taxes, ease of registering the company, laws, stability in country, etc. I can't really tell exactly what I need, I'm just software engineer who want's the answer. At least some educational material or source, I can't really afford to learn laws for each country in the world and then decide :) Maybe you know where I can buy the answer, whatever.?

Comment: This is called "operating as a foreign corporation" and it doesn't necessarily make it such that you avoid paying taxes wherever your business is actually operating.  What you're attempting to do is not new.  For certain business activities, you're going to be required to register in your client's venue as a foreign corporation.

Answer (score 5):

I heard from many people that Gibraltar has good taxation. You should check it out.

Others opened a company in Germany as it has a great refunds and benefits for companies.

The third group opened a company in South America (I think Chile) as it gives great benefits to any foreigner who wants to open a company.

It would be great that you come back here with the result of your investigation and let us know which one was really the best.

Comment: Indeed, I heard about Chile, however I wanted that somebody here would reply with the result of their investigation :)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at different websites such as [The Sovereign Man](http://www.sovereignman.com) and other sites as they have done research in this area.

Also I have  found [this](http://flagtheory.com/the-best-place-for-an-internet-entrepreneur-to-incorporate/) article to be quite helpful as it breaks down the top three to four countries to Incorporate or to make an LLC.

Comment: Do you have any feedback about sovereign man? Their marketing campaigns looks even worse than MacKeeper therefore destroying any trust immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Poland and Bulgaria has very low taxes on freelance software developers. Poland taxes on software developers are 12% flat up to 2 millions euros + about 600 euros in social security contributions.